# javascript - covert an array to key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am new to javascript and I am trying to covert the array into key value pair.

`var arrayA = [{"name":"orange", "value":"1"}, {"name":"banana", "value":"2"}...]`

so the end result would look like `var arrayB = {orange:1, banana:2}`

I feel like I might have to use loop within a loop first to split on `,` and then another one to split on `:`, but that seems messy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following loop: create a new object with the key `name` and the value `value` of each object in `arrayA`

```
var arrayA = [{"name":"orange", "value":"1"}, {"name":"banana", "value":"2"}...]
var obj = {}
$.each(arrayA,function(i,v){
 obj[v.name] = v.value;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z8h6omo6/

or without jquery

```
 for(i in arrayA){
     obj[arrayA[i].name] = arrayA[i].value;
    };
```

Comment: Care should be used with `for..in` for posterity in case of any additional inherited properties.

Comment: `for..in` will iterate over /all/ properties, including inherited ones. No guarantees on order are made either which makes it even more dangerous for arrays.

Comment: i assumed that the array has the same structure

Answer (score 0):

When I have done my codes, there are already two answers. But I don't want to give up, So I write this.

```
var arrayA = [{"name":"orange", "value":"1"}, {"name":"banana", "value":"2"}];

var arr={};
for(var i = arrayA.length -1; i>=0; i--){
  arr[Object.values(arrayA[i])[0]]=Object.values(arrayA[i])[1];
}

console.log(arr);
```

**It should work in next year,** if it doesn't, then check it in the year after next year, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce seems like a good candidate as it will iterate in order and only vist own properties that exist:

```js
var arrayA = [{"name":"orange", "value":"1"}, {"name":"banana", "value":"2"}];

var obj = arrayA.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc[obj.name] = obj.value;
  return acc;
},{});

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object, because reduce returns always the same, and thit is no necessary, because only one property is added.

```js
var array = [{"name":"orange", "value":"1"}, {"name":"banana", "value":"2"}],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function(a) {
  object[a.name] = a.value;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```